# How to uninstall Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, uninstall

I was trying to install ubuntu 13.04 on a mini notebook acer, but an error occurred while almost completing the installation...
Now it doesn't charge, only if I enter the Windows 7 partition.
How do I start the process?
Or can I uninstall the ubuntu to start again to install it?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: What error did you see?

Comment: ***Yes.*** You can re-install **Ubuntu**, replacing your earlier attempt (and still leaving Windows 7 intact). *This is a standard option, in the install process.*

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to take to safely uninstall Ubuntu from a dual-boot setup:

1. Boot into your Live CD for Ubuntu
2. Start a Terminal session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Type `gksudo gparted` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Delete your Ubuntu partitions (you should have two, the main partition and swap). If you are unsure of which partition is your main Ubuntu partition, type `sudo df` in a Terminal session and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will be the filesystem mounted on "/".
5. Expand your Windows partition (it should now be the biggest partition) onto the free space by right clicking it and selecting Resize/Move
6. Reboot into a Windows CD
7. Choose Repair
8. Choose Command Prompt
9. Type `bootrec /fixmbr` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
10. Type `bootrec /fiboot` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
11. Reboot. Your computer should now boot into Windows XP.
12. Profit!

If you want a full guide on how uninstall Ubuntu, see [this website](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/).